# Sumprea SFM5020

Tags: pi-3, serial

Somebody help me to talk with suprema SFM5020, i read datasheet and some comands, init this code but don't work...

```
import serial

comport = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)

result = comport.readline()
print(result)
comport.close()
```

if somebody have tutorial or help me with this, please help me.

[Suprema SFM5020-OP5](https://www.supremainc.com/sites/default/files/uf_sfm5020-op5_datasheet_v1.2.pdf)

[image]

This is terminal response and commands used:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pysfm
>>> module = pysfm.Module('/dev/ttyAMA0')
>>> module.connect()
[SEND] : 40 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 0A 
[EXCEPTION : read_response_command] Packet cannot be read.
False
>>>
```

Comment: i don't know if connected ok or not, somebody can help me with check this ?

Comment: when i write or read, python shell stop for long time...

Comment: Please edit your question and add 1) a link to the datasheet of the device and 2) the commands you use to run your script plus 3) the systems response.

Comment: When try connect on serial, i received some error, i think is problem with serial port on gpio 14,15...

Comment: You have given no evidence that you are actually running the script.  Please include the terminal command you use and the terminal response.

Comment: I think uart is not free for use, you know how test it ?